# Construct 2 MediaPlayer error

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, construct-2

Hei guys, all right?
So... I'm trying finish a game exported from construct 2 on HTML5 and When I use WebChromeClient on WebView or PhoneGap with Emulator (on my phone not work too).

I get this error when the sound have to start: 03-01 18:08:14.891: E/MediaPlayer(543): error (1, -2147483648)
Where i'm wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: can i post on rar? Sorry is just big to put only the code here.

Comment: So where i understand, the javascript call some class in java that's execute the audio, but the audio don't start.

Comment: About the code posting- It's probably best just to post the offending part of your code. Try to limit it to a function or a couple lines, and we can let you know if it needs to be larger.

Comment: So Blue Ice, i can't post my code, because he is exported (javascript) from Construct 2 (HTML5). So what i want to know why i have this error on android.

Comment: All lines with this, i have delete:

Comment: 151: //this.recorder.prepare(); 
559: //this.player.prepare(); 
42: mp.prepare(); 
178: //player.prepare();

Comment: i thought that is was the cause of the error. But don't. The problem continue